# max-width and min-width scaling, is this possible?

Tags: html, css

**What I would like to do**

I got a table with 3 columns:

- Text Content
- Input Content
- Spacer

The Text and Input must be max 200px and min 100px

I want them to be 200px---200px---????px (rest of screen width)

I only want them to scale smaller when screen is less than 400px

Then they should scale down nicely until 100px--100px--0px

[image]

How can this be done?

I tried but it seems to ignore min/max with both table and divs.

```
<table style="width:100%;" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td style="">
      <div style="width:10%; min-width:100px; max-width:200px; width:auto;">
        The text goes here
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="">
      <input style="width:10%; min-width:100px; max-width:200px; width:auto;" 
             type="text" value="field is here">
    </td>
    <td style="width:80%;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

*(I use inline styles because its quicker when testing, will put in CSS once it works)*

Comment: Sounds like a case for flexbox..not a table.

Comment: I looked at some flexbox examples, https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp  it does not look very responsive. Do you have some responsive examples?

Comment: Flexbox is **entirely** responsive.

Comment: Do I take that on faith or can you prove it :-)

Comment: It's built to be responsive if you've seen demos you must have seen that.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/prjKyZ

Comment: ^_^ Flexbox is most certainly more responsive than tables ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
  }

  .text {
    background: yellow;
  }

  .input {
    background: pink;
  }

  .text,
  .input {
    width: 100px;
  }
  .spacer {
    background: orange;
    display: none;
  }

  @media (min-width: 400px) {
    .text,
    .input {
      width: 200px;
    }

    .spacer {
      display: table-cell;
      width: calc(100% - 400px);
    }
  }
```

```html
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="text">1</td>
    <td class="input">2</td>
    <td class="spacer">3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That worked PERFECTLY!!!  Thanks a lot EugenAz!!!  This was exactly what I was looking for and it fits into all my code.

Comment: According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) it's supported since IE9.

Comment: Eugen, all I had to do was add your spacer class to my tables and its pretty great how cool I can make them now :-)  Check it out... https://db.tt/Z6k8HHeZ20

Comment: @torbenrudgaard I'm glad i could help you! :)